# Pandas multiple column groupby plot to show first level group on x axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas groupby on multiple columns:

```
df_nomiss.groupby([pd.Grouper(level="Days", freq="D"),"Rep_name_or_ID_ENG"])["HCP_ID"].nunique().plot(legend=None)
```

The code works great but my problem is that instead of having the "Days" (which is a DateTimeIndex by the way) to be shown on the x axis I have "Days, Rep_name_or_ID_ENG" shown with no figures as you can see below:

[image]

Instead of this I would like to have only the datetimeindex "Days" to be shown on the x axis with date figures.

Could you please help me on how to achieve it?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: it's better to operate with initial dataframe which you might post

Comment: Such problems have been reported frequently. However, to see if there is a solution, you would want to make your case reproducible. See [mcve].